# Delete specific files/folders from volume shadow copy backups

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, volume-shadow-service

I need to erase some files/folders from disk completely, including shadow copies. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of the ability to selectively remove a file from a shadow copy. The only way would be to purge all old shadow copies.

Comment: If I delete a folder than re-create a new one with the same name, old versions can be recovered from shadow copies. So if I delete a folder, old versions remain. A file recovery utility might be able to find them that's what I don't want.